# How to deny access to any system user who attempts to log in without password usage?

Tags: mysql

I have `mysql-server-5.5` in `Ubuntu Server 12.04`

I realized that when typing `mysql` command logged as **any system user** I got access to mysql, despite I can only display `test` and `information_schema` databases, how can I disable this accesses?

I don't have those users registered on `mysql` so I don't want this to have access.

This is what happens

```
user-one@server:~$ mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 39950
Server version: 5.5.38-0ubuntu0.12.04.1-log (Ubuntu)...

mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

user-two@server:~$ mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 39950
Server version: 5.5.38-0ubuntu0.12.04.1-log (Ubuntu)...

mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When looking as **root** for this users in case they are registered

```
mysql> use mysql
mysql> SELECT * FROM user WHERE User = 'user-one';
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM user WHERE User = 'user-two';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `''@localhost`, and other bunch of accounts exist in a freshly installed MySQL instance.

If you execute `SELECT user()` you may see something like this:

```
mysql> SELECT user();
+--------------------+
| user()             |
+--------------------+
| user-one@localhost |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

That user doesn't really exist, and it is actually mapped for authentication and authorization to:

```
mysql> SELECT current_user();
+----------------+
| current_user() |
+----------------+
| ''@localhost   |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In order to fix this, **run the script [`mysql_secure_installation`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-secure-installation.html) always after setting up a production database**, and it will ask you to set a mysql root password, delete remote access and delete the passwordless default accounts. This should be part of any proper mysql installation process, and [it is documented here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/default-privileges.html).

Starting with 5.6 and 5.7, better security defaults are used, but only on official packages.

Remember that by default, all users have write permissions to write on `test%` databases. That is a very dangerous default, and should be fixed before production.

Comment: if I run this script in production environment, will this affect in something?

Comment: @tachomi it affects the grant privilege tables. Test it beforehand so none of your applications is using one of the anonymous users. Alternatively, you can manually delete `''@localhost` user and other grants, but it is not trivial.

Comment: If I'm pretty sure my apps aren't using any of this users, can I make it?

Comment: @tachomi Sure, it only edits the mysql.* tables.

Comment: Awesome buddy, thanks a lot for the advice and the complete information.